# Add Working Days to Start Date to Create End Date (including Bank Holiday)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've modified this access function so I can work out the end date given the amount of working days.

However I need to be able to take **uk bank holidays** into consideration as well.

Anybody got any good idea how I could do that ?

```
Public Function CountDays(startDate As Date, NoOfDays As Integer) As Date
' Function to count no of working days
Dim tmpNo As Integer
Dim tmpDate As Date
Dim tmpStartDate As Date
Dim i As Integer

tmpNo = NoOfDays

tmpStartDate = startDate

tmpDate = startDate

i = 0

Do Until i = NoOfDays

If Weekday(tmpDate) = 1 Or Weekday(tmpDate) = 7 Then
tmpNo = tmpNo + 1
Else
i = i + 1
End If
tmpDate = tmpDate + 1
Loop

CountDays = DateAdd("d", tmpNo, tmpStartDate)
End Function
```

cheers

Ross

Answer (score 2):

No need to loop through every day. A bit of calculation will get you the number of weekdays, then do a table lookup for the number of holidays in that time frame. So:

```
TotalDays = DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate) + 1

TotalWeekends = (DateDiff("ww", startDate, endDate) * 2) + _ 
((DatePart("w", startDate) = vbSunday) *-1) + _ 
((DatePart("w", endDate) = vbSaturday) *-1)

TotalHolidays = DCount("*","tblHolidays","Holiday Between #" & startdate & "# And #" & enddate & "#")

TotalWorkingDays = TotalDays - TotalWeekends - TotalHolidays
```

By the way, if you use the # around the dates, Access assumes it's in the US format. You can use quotes instead.

Answer (score 0):

As UK bank holidays differ each year, you would need to create a table to store these dates in, and then check this table in your code and increase your tmpNo value if the date exists.

Change the code by adding in an extra 'Else If' clause as follows:

```
Do Until i = NoOfDays
    If Weekday(tmpDate) = 1 Or Weekday(tmpDate) = 7 Then
        tmpNo = tmpNo + 1
    Else If DCount("*","tblExceptionDates","dtmDate = #" & tmpDate & "#") > 0 Then
        tmpNo = tmpNo + 1
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
    tmpDate = tmpDate + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Also, you may want to amend the date criteria slightly, as sometimes UK and US dates get mixed up. To be safe I normally would use `"dtmDate = DateValue(""" & Format(tmpDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & """)"` rather than `"dtmDate = #" & tmpDate & "#"` if I encounter a problem.